# Get DOM of another page, different server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get DOM from another page which is on different server and read some data from DOM.

Example: I have my page where I try to get DOM (via javascript/jquery) from `https://stackoverflow.com/` and extract the title and print on my page.

I could archive that and how?

Comment: Research "screen scraping"

Comment: Also note that screen scraping cannot be done using JS due to the Same Origin POlicy. You would need to do it server side

Comment: I don't want via "screen". I want to get DOM in background, like HTTP request.

Comment: You didn't even search for "screen scraping", did you? If you did, you would know that "screen scraping" is just a different term for "web scraping".

Comment: @CodeF0x I did, but what I found was to load page (visually) to scrap it.